# Spring jdbc bug?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring, jdbc

I'm using MySQL database and have written some procedures. If I try to create these procedures with spring jdbc I get error messages that these procedures already exist. If I connect the old fashion way with DriverManager create a PreparedStatement and execute it everything works just fine.
Does anyone know why this is happening?

here in code what I am doing

```
...
connection = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
...
for(String sql: sqlScript.split( "(;)" ) ){
    connection.execute(sql.trim());
}
```

this results in SQL-Exception that the procedure I give as parameter already exists. But if I exchange the preceding code snippet against this:

```
for(final String sql: sqlScript.split( "(;/)" ) ) {
     if (sql.trim().length() > 0)
        try {
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?"
                                                                    + "user=root" );
            PreparedStatement ps =
            conn.prepareCall(sql);
            ps.execute();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

everything works fine...

Would be nice if anyone knows whats wrong here...

at least one of my procedures that already exists... probably even in your database...

```
create procedure insertUser(
    in p_firstname varchar(50),
    in p_lastname varchar(50),
    in p_username varchar(25)
)
  begin
    declare l_username varchar(25);
    select username into l_username
        from movielist.user where username = p_username;
    if l_username is null then
        insert into movielist.User (firstname, lastname, username) values
        (p_firstname, p_lastname, p_username);
    end if;
  end;/
```

Comment: Can you show the error? I have a hunch, but not sure.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
 at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:403)
 at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(LauncherImpl.java:47)
 at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(LauncherImpl.java:115)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [CREATE PROCEDURE insertUser

Comment: Please post the full stack trace as an edit in your question. I think what you posted was trimmed.

Comment: It looks like you're checking to see if username already exists in the table, and then inserting it.   Is there a reason why you don't use a primary key, and then catch an exception if the insert fails?  Not sure you need a stored procedure for this.